# Could not load file or assembly System.Net, Version=2.0.5.0

Tags: c#, .net, assembly-binding-redirect

I have an ASP.NET 4.5.2 application that loads the `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient` library. When it tries to connect, the following error occurs:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

```
  File Name: "System.Net, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"
   bei System.Data.Services.Client.UriResolver.ConvertToAbsoluteUri(Uri baseUri)
   bei System.Data.Services.Client.UriResolver.ConvertToAbsoluteAndValidateBaseUri(Uri& baseUri, String parameterName)
   bei System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext..ctor(Uri serviceRoot, DataServiceProtocolVersion maxProtocolVersion, ClientEdmModel model)
   bei Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.Extensions.DataServiceContextWrapper..ctor(Uri serviceRoot, DataServiceProtocolVersion maxProtocolVersion, Func`1 accessTokenGetter, IEnumerable`1 customTypeMappings)
   bei Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.ActiveDirectoryClient..ctor(Uri serviceRoot, Func`1 accessTokenGetter,...
```

I have added a binding redirect to my web.config already:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net" publicKeyToken="7cec85d7bea7798e" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.5.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

But the problem persists. What is wrong here?

Comment: It seems you're trying to use a .Net 2.0 dll in a 4.0 project.

Comment: So it seems the DLL I am using requires a .NET 2.0 DLL, although that DLL is really recent. Is there a possibility to tell that DLL to use a .NET 4.5.2 DLL?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx

Comment: @mcNets How would it do that with a nuget package DLL?

Comment: I have updated the nuget package in my application from 2.1.0 to 2.1.1 today, but the problem persists.

Comment: I've just generated a new `ASP.Net Web Site (Razor v3)`, then I've added `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient` and it compiles fine and I can run it in Internet Explorer.

Comment: @HansPassant That sounds interesting, can you recommend any further reading about that?

Comment: I have no single occurrence of "AppDomain.AssemblyResolve" in my code. Not sure about the referenced libraries, though...

Comment: @mcNets as can be seen in the stack trace, the GraphClient library throws up not at startup, but in the constructor. Did you call the constructor?

Comment: No, I only added it to new project.

Comment: @HansPassant Could `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APPBASE","..")` cause this issue? This is the only occurrence of `AppDomain` in my whole codebase.